# How to get a list of files with errors in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

In PhpStorm I get a read mark on the upper right side of the code window if there's a PHP bug in the file. That's great. What I like to have is a list of all files which have this read mark.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well ... try this: `Code | Inspect Code` -- in results window you will have an option to export results as text file, which will include file names. You will be able to see file names directly in that window when choosing correct grouping options (there are plenty of buttons there -- check tooltips for them or help page for that window).

Comment: I don't need a text list. I need a list to quickly go through and fix the errors. So Inspect Code helps a lot. Unfortunately I get a lot of errors in 3rd party code. Is there a way to exclude some directories from code inspection?

Comment: You can run inspection on certain directories or custom defined Scopes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments. That's what I was looking for. Feal free to add you comments as answers in order you get the credits.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

To get the list of all files with errors and warnings use `Code` | **Inspect Code**. It's possible to specify what inspection profile to use, which directories to scan. Custom **Scope** provides a flexible way to include/exclude certain directories or files from the inspection results.

Answer (score 7):

Slightly off-topic, but may be helpful. If you need to jump through all the errors in a file (for example, CSS file), open up the file and and hit the `F2` button on the keyboard. Repeat it to cycle through all the errors. To navigate back to the previous error, hit `Shift + F2`